# Tomcat, help generating wsdl with reference to static variable

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

Having issues generating a wsdl for 1 out of 2 endpoints in my webapp for tomcat. The jws file which does not compile has error (`error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No compiler found in your classpath!`  (you may need to add `tools.jar`)).

I have pin pointed it down to the static variable call the `Authorisation.jws`(file which does not compile) file makes to the `Login.jws` file. Can you make static variable calls in webapps like this? If not what is the correct procedure?

```
public class Authorisation{

    //Authorises inputted session key with current active session keys
    public Boolean authorise(String key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Login.KEYS.length; i++)
        {
            if (key.equals(Login.KEYS[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out. If anyone has a similar issue, the solution is that the jws files cannot reference the static variables in a different file so you must create a package with your static variables and place them in the WEB-INF/classes folder.